# Есть ли утечка памяти при вызове CComPtr и QueryInterface?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, интерфейс, com, atl

Подскажите, этот код имеет право на существование или нет?

```cpp
HRESULT CMyClass::Assign(IUnknown * src) {
    if (!src)
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    HRESULT res;
    ATL::CComPtr<IAddress> addr;
    res = src->QueryInterface<IAddress>(&addr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(res))
        return addr->getStreet(*this->street);
    else
        return res;
}
```

Что меня смущает. В конструкторе класса `CBasePtr`, который является родительским классом для класса `CComPtr`, я вижу вызов `AddRef()`. Но `QueryInterface`, по идее уже сам вызывает `AddRef()`, т.е. получится утечка памяти. Или т.к. в `QueryInterface` передается указатель, то дополнительный `AddRef()` вызываться не будет?

Comment: В приведенном коде CBasePtr не видать, и вообще, он не собирается.

Comment: @user7860670 `CBasePtr` родитель `CComPtr`. И в каком месте он не собирается?

Comment: Да в самом начале - символ STDMETHODIMP не определен. Как вы умудрились заработать 30к репутации, но не быть в курсе, что в вопросе требуется приводить [mcve]?

Comment: @user7860670 `STDMETHODIMP` - это стандартный макрос, определенный в `winnt.h`. Убрал его из кода

Comment: @user7860670 минимальный пример не означает, что нужно копировать в пример все из стандартных заголовков, особенно если пример не про отладку, а про поведение стандартной библиотеки при определенном порядке вызовов.

Comment: @PashaPash Полностью с вами согласен.

Comment: @user7860670 тогда почему вопрос про поведение стандартной библиотеки закрыт как "просьба помочь с отладкой, вы не привели код стандартной библиотеки" :)?

Comment: @PashaPash Вам явно стоит перечитать причину закрытия более внимательно.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за совет, думаю я точно знаю, для чего эта причина закрытия должна использоваться, т.к. я один из тех, кто эти самые причины закрытия формулировал. Эта причина закрытия подразумевает что (1) топикастер попросил помочь с отладкой **и при этом** (2) не привел пример кода, который можно скопировать локально и отладить. Вопросы, не подразумевающие отладку, под эту причину не попадают. Данный вопрос отладку явно не подразумевает.

Comment: @PashaPash Все четко - вопрос про работоспособность конкретного кода, а приведенный пример скопировать локально и отладить нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос не про работоспособность. Текущий код у топикастера работает, и он не просит что-то подправить чтобы "восстановить работоспособность".  Вопрос про поведение библиотеки при определенном порядке вызовов. Это чисто теоретический вопрос, на который вполне может ответить исходя из текста вопроса любой, кто работал с ATL. Механизм закрытия на сайте - это способ отсеивать вопросы, на которые никак нельзя дать ответ без дополнительной правки со стороны автора. Об этом достаточно подробно расписано на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/

Comment: @user7860670 ну или иначе можно просто закрывать 90% вопросов по схеме "в вопросе есть код? значит отвечающему может захотется его скопировать и отладить - значит этот вопрос про отладку!".

Comment: @PashaPash Так оно и есть. Для разных топиков по-разному, но для C / C++ c  их требовательностью к контексту пачки вопросов с обрывками кода, требующими от читателя делать зыбкие предположения о том, что скрывается за взявшимися из ниоткуда идентификаторами, какие заголовочные файлы подключатся, как потом это все собирается, - это насущная проблема.

Comment: @user7860670 ну тогда пожалуйста идите на мету, и проведите это как правило. Потому что сейчас правил "весь код - это просьба отладки" и "можно закрывать все, где есть хоть один неизвестный лично мне идентификатор" нет. То, что лично вы не ориентируетесь в каком-то куске стандартной библиотеки не превращает все вопросы на SO в оффтопик. Это просто означает, что на некоторые вопросы вы не можете ответить. "я не могу ответить на этот вопрос" - это не причина закрытия.

Comment: @PashaPash Дело не в том, что "неизвестный лично мне идентификатор", а в том, что в языке С/C++ существуют вполне конкретные формальные правила, позволяющие определить, чем является тот или иной идентификатор, и эти правила не применимы для произвольно вырванных клочков кода. Вот и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базовым классом для CComPtr у меня в VS2017 является CComPtrBase. Вот его конструкторы (из atlcomcli.h):

```
CComPtrBase() throw()
{
    p = NULL;
}
CComPtrBase(_Inout_opt_ T* lp) throw()
{
    p = lp;
    if (p != NULL)
        p->AddRef();
}
```

Как видно, здесь есть вызов AddRef, но только в конструкторе с параметром. Этот конструктор вызывался бы в коде вида `ATL::CComPtr<IAddress> addr(somePointer);`. В вашем случае же вызывается конструктор без параметра, а затем в пустой экземпляр CComPtr записывается адрес из QueryInterface. AddRef будет вызван только один раз (в QueryInterface).

Сказать, есть ли утечка памяти, по приведенному неполному коду нельзя. Если в метод передается правильная реализация IUnknown, то ее не должно быть, в том смысле, что в этом коде нечему вызвать утечку памяти. Есть ли утечка памяти в вашем реальном коде можно узнать с помощью отладчика, поставив точку останова на метод Release в COM-объекте. Если все нормально, при последнем вызове Release счетчик ссылок должен быть равен нулю.